# Sinon not working with Require and Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, require, sinon

I am following [this](http://tinnedfruit.com/2011/04/26/testing-backbone-apps-with-jasmine-sinon-3.html) tutorial and I am trying to stub out an object.  Here is my code:

```
define(function(require) {
  var sinon = require('sinon');
  beforeEach(function() {
    this.patientStub = sinon.stub(window, "Patient");
    this.model = new Backbone.Model({
      id: 5,
      title: "Foo"
    });
  });
});
```

I keep getting the error `TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property Patient as function`.  There is very little info on SO or online and none of it has been helpful.  I don't know if this makes any difference, but here is my directory structure.

```
Patient ->  index.html
            karma.conf.js
            css -> 
            js -> 
            test ->
```

The object I am trying to mock is located at js/models/Patient.js.  Please, any help will be great.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you try to mock a function that is not present (means `undefined`) when your test runs. You should load the file in your `index.html` otherwise it will not become vissible in the global namespace. Its also not common to load `sinon` with requireJs in a test, normally you would put this in your `index.html` as well

Comment: I am just learning about TDD and trying to get my setup going.  What I am understanding is that I need to load my models and views in my test index.html.  If I do this then it will work with Sinon.  Do you know of a place where I could get some more information about Sinon with Jasmine/Karma/Require?  I know that is kind of a specialized setup.